how to find font type on webapp folder or apk code version
I'm trying to to find the font type on webapp folder or apk code version
I tried using font xplorer x but it's not working as I want, actually, I need a tool to use the locally loaded version of code by webapp or web aplication, please let me know what is the best way to find fonts on projects.
